# How to merge multiple Distribution Lists in Exchange at server level?

Tags: list, email, exchange-server, group

The goal is that other colleagues can send an email to a distribution list that contains several other lists.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand your question correct but Distribution Lists are just Mail enabled Active Directory Groups, so in order to "merge" the Recipients, just nest the Groups in any way. Maybe create a parent group, mail enable the group and add the desired child groups to the parent.

Two conditions must be fulfilled for messages to go thru, no sender restriction must be in placed which prevents the sender to address any of the groups and every group has to be mail enabled.